# Extraer coordenadas de una direccion con la API de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, google-maps

Estoy construyendo un mapa con marcadores personalizados sacados de una base de datos MySQL

Tengo la siguiente var en js con diferentes coordenadas

```js
var locations = [
        {lat: 41.641581, lng: -4.780962},
        {lat: 41.681581, lng: -4.740961},
        {lat: 41.661481, lng: -4.710061},
      ]
```

El problema es que en mi base de datos no se guardan las coordenadas, sino la dirección completa, desde el siguiente enlace de ejemplo se pueden extraer las coordenadas de las direcciones.

```html
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=C/ de las eras 9 - Iscar&key=MI_API_KEY
```

Quisiera saber si se puede obtener las coordenadas de una direccion directamente desde un script en js sin tener que pasar por ese enlace. Y si no se pudiera ¿Cómo extraigo las coordenadas de ese archivo?

Comment: Sí se puede. Debes usar la api de geocodificación de google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: La verdad que no se muy bien cómo geocodificar direcciones automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Entra a probar el código y pones tu api key

```js
$.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=C/%20de%20las%20eras%209%20-%20Iscar&key=TU_API_KEY', 
  function(data) {
    console.log(data.results[0].geometry.location);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si, la cuestión es "extraer" de ese archivo el parametro "location" para incluirlo en la variable de arriba

Comment: Te actualizo la respuesta para ponerte cómo se haría con jQuery, por ejemplo

Comment: ¿Te sirvió de algo lo que te puse?

Comment: Perdona, no respondí, lo probé y me dice que la variable $.get no está definida

Comment: Revisar [answer].